# Bootstrap 4: Two Vertical Pill Tab Navs Adjacent Active Tabs in Sync

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

The title is probably very confusing as couldn't think of the right words to describe this and thus while also having trouble Googling for solutions.

On this page: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/navs/

[image]

One can easily create vertical tabs using the framework. However, I'm looking to also have tabs to the right of the content that controls the content in the middle. Once again, not hard as you can simply copy the pill code from the left and add into a row on the right.

The problem is if I select say the 2nd item on the left want the adjacent tab on (2nd on right) to also become active. Or if I choose the 3rd item on right for instance, the 3rd item on left would also become active. So like the following:

[image]

Want to use as much native Bootstrap 4 code as possible, but assuming their isn't native way to accomplish, then presumably jquery to keep the adjacent pill active class in sync. Or if there is a name for this design technique so that I may better search for it.

Also while the standard tab code can be seen on the linked bootstrap linked page also pasting below my modified three column version which works except for keeping the adjacent tab active class in sync as noted:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
        <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="false">Dog</a>
        <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Cat</a>
        <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-messages-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-messages" aria-selected="true">Snake</a>
        <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-settings-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-settings" aria-selected="false">Spider</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab">
          <p>Cillum ad ut irure tempor velit nostrud occaecat ullamco aliqua anim Lorem sint. Veniam sint duis incididunt do esse magna mollit excepteur laborum qui. Id id reprehenderit sit est eu aliqua occaecat quis et velit excepteur laborum mollit dolore eiusmod. Ipsum dolor in occaecat commodo et voluptate minim reprehenderit mollit pariatur. Deserunt non laborum enim et cillum eu deserunt excepteur ea incididunt minim occaecat.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-profile-tab">
          <p>Culpa dolor voluptate do laboris laboris irure reprehenderit id incididunt duis pariatur mollit aute magna pariatur consectetur. Eu veniam duis non ut dolor deserunt commodo et minim in quis laboris ipsum velit id veniam. Quis ut consectetur adipisicing officia excepteur non sit. Ut et elit aliquip labore Lorem enim eu. Ullamco mollit occaecat dolore ipsum id officia mollit qui esse anim eiusmod do sint minim consectetur qui.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade active show" id="v-pills-messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-messages-tab">
          <p>Fugiat id quis dolor culpa eiusmod anim velit excepteur proident dolor aute qui magna. Ad proident laboris ullamco esse anim Lorem Lorem veniam quis Lorem irure occaecat velit nostrud magna nulla. Velit et et proident Lorem do ea tempor officia dolor. Reprehenderit Lorem aliquip labore est magna commodo est ea veniam consectetur.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-settings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-settings-tab">
          <p>Eu dolore ea ullamco dolore Lorem id cupidatat excepteur reprehenderit consectetur elit id dolor proident in cupidatat officia. Voluptate excepteur commodo labore nisi cillum duis aliqua do. Aliqua amet qui mollit consectetur nulla mollit velit aliqua veniam nisi id do Lorem deserunt amet. Culpa ullamco sit adipisicing labore officia magna elit nisi in aute tempor commodo eiusmod.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<div class="col-3">
      <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
        <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="false">Lab</a>
        <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Siamese</a>
        <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-messages-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-messages" aria-selected="true">Python</a>
        <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-settings-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-settings" aria-selected="false">Black Widow</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `trigger` the corresponding button in the corresponding column on each click... just need to ensure that we don't get stuck in a loop which is why we introduce a `setTimeout` since bootstrap.js takes some time to set/edit classes

This will hopefully get you what you're aiming for...

**Working snippet** below:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  var TimeOutNumber = 10;

  $('#v-pills-dog').click(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      $('#v-pills-dog2').hasClass('active') ? '' : $('#v-pills-dog2').trigger('click');
    }, TimeOutNumber);
  });
  $('#v-pills-dog2').click(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      $('#v-pills-dog').hasClass('active') ? '' : $('#v-pills-dog').trigger('click');
    }, TimeOutNumber);
  });

  $('#v-pills-cat').click(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      $('#v-pills-cat2').hasClass('active') ? '' : $('#v-pills-cat2').trigger('click');
    }, TimeOutNumber);
  });
  $('#v-pills-cat2').click(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      $('#v-pills-cat').hasClass('active') ? '' : $('#v-pills-cat').trigger('click');
    }, TimeOutNumber);
  });

  $('#v-pills-snake').click(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      $('#v-pills-snake2').hasClass('active') ? '' : $('#v-pills-snake2').trigger('click');
    }, TimeOutNumber);
  });
  $('#v-pills-snake2').click(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      $('#v-pills-snake').hasClass('active') ? '' : $('#v-pills-snake').trigger('click');
    }, TimeOutNumber);
  });

  $('#v-pills-spider').click(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      $('#v-pills-spider2').hasClass('active') ? '' : $('#v-pills-spider2').trigger('click');
    }, TimeOutNumber);
  });
  $('#v-pills-spider2').click(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      $('#v-pills-spider').hasClass('active') ? '' : $('#v-pills-spider').trigger('click');
    }, TimeOutNumber);
  });

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Toggleable Pills</h2>
  <br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
        <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-dog" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="false">Dog</a>
        <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-cat" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Cat</a>
        <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-snake" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-messages" aria-selected="true">Snake</a>
        <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-spider" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-settings" aria-selected="false">Spider</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab">
          <p><b>DOG - LAB</b> Cillum ad ut irure tempor velit nostrud occaecat ullamco aliqua anim Lorem sint. Veniam sint duis incididunt do esse magna mollit excepteur laborum qui. Id id reprehenderit sit est eu aliqua occaecat quis et velit excepteur
            laborum mollit dolore eiusmod. Ipsum dolor in occaecat commodo et voluptate minim reprehenderit mollit pariatur. Deserunt non laborum enim et cillum eu deserunt excepteur ea incididunt minim occaecat.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-profile-tab">
          <p><b>CAT - SIAMESE</b> Culpa dolor voluptate do laboris laboris irure reprehenderit id incididunt duis pariatur mollit aute magna pariatur consectetur. Eu veniam duis non ut dolor deserunt commodo et minim in quis laboris ipsum velit id veniam.
            Quis ut consectetur adipisicing officia excepteur non sit. Ut et elit aliquip labore Lorem enim eu. Ullamco mollit occaecat dolore ipsum id officia mollit qui esse anim eiusmod do sint minim consectetur qui.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade active show" id="v-pills-messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-messages-tab">
          <p><b>SNAKE - PYTHON</b> Fugiat id quis dolor culpa eiusmod anim velit excepteur proident dolor aute qui magna. Ad proident laboris ullamco esse anim Lorem Lorem veniam quis Lorem irure occaecat velit nostrud magna nulla. Velit et et proident Lorem
            do ea tempor officia dolor. Reprehenderit Lorem aliquip labore est magna commodo est ea veniam consectetur.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-settings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-settings-tab">
          <p><b>SPIDER - BLACK SPIDER</b> Eu dolore ea ullamco dolore Lorem id cupidatat excepteur reprehenderit consectetur elit id dolor proident in cupidatat officia. Voluptate excepteur commodo labore nisi cillum duis aliqua do. Aliqua amet qui mollit
            consectetur nulla mollit velit aliqua veniam nisi id do Lorem deserunt amet. Culpa ullamco sit adipisicing labore officia magna elit nisi in aute tempor commodo eiusmod.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
        <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-dog2" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="false">Lab</a>
        <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-cat2" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Siamese</a>
        <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-snake2" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-messages" aria-selected="true">Python</a>
        <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-spider2" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-settings" aria-selected="false">Black Widow</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This sounds very promising. Thank you so much. Will try today and then update here accordingly.

Comment: That you were able to under stand my issue (even though I didn't explain as well as normal), and gave such a straight forward solution is incredible helpful. Works perfectly. Will review the code more as well to better learn exactly how it works and hopefully this will be helpful to others who run into the same need. You rock Akber!